# How to make Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient asynchronous

Tags: xmlhttprequest, httpclient, titanium-sdk

My application is getting slow when I try to make the Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient call though I'm making the call in the Alloy.js and the webservice is not depended on the screen as its a background call.

```
Alloy.Globals.xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    async: true,
    onerror : function(e) {

     },
     timeout : 9000  // in milliseconds
});
```

My screen is getting halted until I get the response. How to call the service in background without effecting the screen/application performance

```
Ti SDK : 8.3.1.GA
Axway Appcelerator Studio, 
build: 5.1.4.201909061933

Android Platform - Not working

iOS Platform - working
```

Comment: if the answer below isn't working please add your Ti SDK version and the platform you are testing on.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the documentation:

```
By default, the HTTPClient makes asynchronous requests. Asynchronous requests do not block the application and use callbacks to process responses when they are received.

Synchronous requests block the execution of the application until it receives a response. On the iOS platform, you can make synchronous requests by setting the optional async parameter to false when calling the open method.

The Android platform does not support synchronous requests.
```

There is no `async` parameter for the constructor, only inside the `open()` method for iOS: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-open (optional 3rd parameter).

So the http request might not be the source for the slow down.

What you could try is to move the HTTPClient part out of the global space into a library or into the controller itself (for testing purposes). I use it in a Podcatcher app without blocking the UI and download multiple files without blocking the UI.

Comment: Thank you for your response and yes its true  that it should not block the application but when I removed the httpclient request and fetch the data from the database that is stored by capturing the response from httpclient request, it works smooth. So their is a problem in httpclient request and waiting for the response i wish i could provide the video clip of it.

Comment: I have updated my question with the platform and SDK information.